# How to call an assembly function from C++ dynamically?

Tags: c++, assembly, dynamic, linker

**REQUIREMENT**: For a certain project we have unique requirement. The application supports an expression language that allows the user to define their own complex expressions that can be evaluated at run time (many hundred times a second) and they need to be executed at machine level for performance.

**WORKING**: Our expression parser translates the script into corresponding assembly language routine perfectly. We checked it by statically linking the object files generated with our C test program and they produce correct result. 
Since the client can change the script anytime, our program (at run time) detects the change, calls the parser which generates the corresponding assembly routine. We then call the assembler from back end to create the object code.

**PROBLEM**

> How can we call this assembly routine dynamically from the C++ program
>   (Loader)?

We are not supposed to call the C++ compiler to link it with the loader because the loader already would have other subroutines running and we cannot take the loader off, recompile and then execute the new loader program.

*I tried searching for a solution online but every time the results are littered with .NET assembly dynamic calling. Our app has nothing to do with .NET.*

Comment: So basically, you want to take some input, generate assembly (which you have complete and working), and then start executing the assembly from within the application that generated it? Is that correct?

Comment: I've never even thought to try to do that... so there may be a better way, but I suppose you could write the assembly out to a simple DLL file and load the DLL during run-time, find the correct function address corresponding to the function containing the assembly you just wrote, and then start calling it...

Comment: @RyanP: No. the program which detects the change is one (A), then there is one that compiles and generates the assembly code (B), then there is a one that has to load and execute which is called loader (C). It is controlled by a separate program (D) which uses nanoMQ to control C and its loaded routines. C & D are continuously running. A executes only on demand while B is executed by A when necessary.

Comment: Understood. I've never done anything like what you are trying to do, so I'm probably not the correct guy to answer your question.. but since no one else is chiming in, I still think you could probably have program B generate a DLL which program D would tell program C to load, and what function name to look for. There is probably a more elegant solution, but if you get nothing else, at least that would probably work...

Comment: We have A, B and D working perfectly. C is there executes, calculates and returns the results. The problem is that C must be able to load the routines dynamically when instructed, I tried looking for code injection at runtime but there seems not much information

Comment: Right... like I said it isn't the most elegant way, but you can write out a DLL that contains your executable assembly that you have created, inside of a function with whatever parameters/return you desire, and then have program C load that during runtime (via LoadLibrary()) and that would accomplish that... on windows. I'm sure you could do something similar with shared objects on linux but I'm not a linux guy so I don't know off of the top of my head.

Comment: We can do this for Windows version but I'm not sure if we can do the same for Linux version.

Comment: Linux can load shared libraries with the `dlopen` function and you can look symbols up using `dlsym`. If your assembly code is standalone you can ask the assembler to produce a plain binary which you can then simply load into memory and execute (take care to set permissions). This should be the least different for windows and linux.

Comment: You should take a look to GModule.

Comment: @SimpleFellow: please **edit your question** to improve it, instead of commenting it. It would be nice to explain a bit more (what kind of application, what is the generated code actually doing, ...)

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch Take a deep breath, clear your mind and then read the question slowly, one line at a time. you will understand "what is the generated code actually doing"

Comment: It is evaluating some expression, but that does not mean anything precise enough.

Comment: Here is precise enough: An expression is a combination of explicit values, constants, variables, operators, and functions that are interpreted according to the particular rules of precedence and of association for a particular programming language, which computes and then produces (returns, in a stateful environment) another value.

Comment: @SimpleFellow: that does not mean much: if you have an expression on heavy values (e.g. on large matrix of quaternion numbers) it is not the same cost as an expression on short integers. Again you need to explain more.

Comment: quanternion numbers? what da hell is dat? It is a financial application for banking so the operators are +, -, *, /, ^, % some predefined financial  functions, temporary variables, basic loops, if-else and a switch case. each script can input one or more values and must returns a single value or an array of values. you cannot have void scripts, i.e. scripts that do not return any values. these are compiled into fast running routines that can be called millions of times depending on the data. Banks have a lot of data, don't they?

Answer (score 6):

First, the "**generated [plugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_%28computing%29)**" approach (on Linux; my answer focuses on Linux but could be adapted to Windows with some effort; you could use many-platform frameworks like [Qt](http://qt.io/) or [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) or Glib from [GTK](http://gtk.org/); then all wrap plugin loading abilities à la `dlopen` with a common API that you could use on Windows, on Linux, on MacOSX, on Android) :

- generate C (or assembly) code in some file `/tmp/generated01.c` (you might even generate C++ code using standard C++ containers, but its compilation would be significantly slower; beware of [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) so emit and use `extern "C"` functions; read the [C++ dlopen mini HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/)). See [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/257873/40065) explaining why generating C is worthwhile (and could be better, and more portable, than generating assembler code).
- run (using `fork`+`execve`+`waitpid`, or simply `system`) a compilation of that generated file into a shared object `/tmp/genenerated01.so` by running `gcc -fPIC -Wall -O /tmp/generated01.c -shared -o /tmp/generated01.so` command; you practically need to get [position-independent code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code), hence the `-fPIC` flag. If using `dlopen` on your generated assembler code you'll need to improve your assembler generator to emit PIC code.
- `dlopen` that new `/tmp/generated01.so` (so use the [dynamic linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker)), see [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html); you could even `remove` the now useless generated C file `/tmp/generated01.c`
- `dlsym` the relevant symbols to get function pointers to the generated code, see [dlsym(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html); your application would simply call the generated code using these function pointers.
- when you are sure that you don't need any functions from it and that no call frame uses it, you could `dlclose` that shared object library (but you might accept to leak some address space by not calling `dlclose` at all)

The above approach is worthwhile and can be used a big lot of times (my [manydl.c](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/manydl.c) demonstrates that you could `dlopen` a million different shared objects), and is practically even compatible (even when emitting C code!) with an *interactive* [Read-Eval-Print-Loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) -on most current desktops and laptops and servers-, since most of the time the generated `/tmp/generated01.c` would be quite small (e.g. a few hundred lines at most) to be very quickly generated and compiled (by  `gcc`, etc...). I am even using this in [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) for its REPL mode. On Linux this plugin approach generally requires to link the main application with `-rdynamic` (so that `dlopen`-ed plugins can reference and call functions from the main application).

---

Then, other approaches could be to **use some [Just-In-Time compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) library**, like

- [GNU lightning](http://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/) (which emits *slow* machine code very quickly - so very short JIT emission time, but the generated code is running slowly since it is very unoptimized)
- [asmjit](https://github.com/kobalicek/asmjit); it is x86-64 specific, and enables you to generate individual x86-64 machine instructions
- GNU [libjit](http://www.gnu.org/software/libjit/) is available for several platforms, and offer an "interpreter" mode for other platforms
- [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) (part of [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) compiler, usable as a JIT library)
- [GCCJIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) (a new JIT library front-end to [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/))

Grossly speaking, the first elements of that list are able to emit JIT machine code fairly quickly, but that code won't run as fast as compiling with `gcc -fPIC -O1` or `-O2` the equivalent generated C code (but would run typically 2x to 5x slower!); the last two elements (LLVM & GCCJIT) are compiler based: so they are able to *optimize* and emit *efficient* code, at the expense of slower JIT code emission. All the JIT libraries are able (like `dlsym` does for plugins) to give function pointers to newly JIT-constructed functions.

Notice that there is a trade-off to be made: some techniques are able to generate quickly some machine code, if you accept that generated code to later run a bit slowly; other techniques (notably GCCJIT or LLVM) are spending time to optimize the generated machine code, so takes more time to emit the machine code, but that code would later run quickly. You should not expect both (small generation time, quick execution time), since there is no such thing as a free lunch.

---

I believe that **generating manually some assembler code is practically not worthwhile**. You won't be able to generate very optimized code (because [optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) is a very [difficult](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/273698/why-are-there-so-few-c-compilers/273711#273711) art, and both GCC and Clang have millions of source line code for optimization passes), unless you spend many years of work for that. Using some JIT library is easier, and "compiling" to C or C++ is also quite easy (you leave the burden of optimization to the C compiler you are calling).

---

You could also consider **rewriting your application into some language with [homoiconicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity) and [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) abilities** (e.g. [multi-stage programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-stage_programming)), such as [Common Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp) (and many others, e.g. those providing [eval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval)). Its [SBCL](http://sbcl.org) implementation is *always* emitting machine code...

You could also **embed an interpreter** like [Lua](http://lua.org) -perhaps even [LuaJit](http://luajit.org/)- or [Guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) in your application. The main advantage of embedding an existing language is that there are resources (books, modules, ...) and community of people knowing them (designing a good language is difficult!). Also, the embedded interpreter library is well designed and probably well debugged (since used a lot), and some of them are fast enough (since using [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode) techniques).

Comment: It was very interesting to know about JIT compilation for C. I assume it creates machine code stuff that can be called dynamically? It if really creates really fast code dynamically then it can be considered. I had never heard of it before.

Comment: You cannot expect short generation time, and quick execution time of the generated code. You need to make some trade-off and benchmark various approaches.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments already suggest, `LoadLibrary` (Windows) and `dlopen` (Linux/POSIX) are by far the easiest solution. These are specifically intended to dynamically load code. Equally important, they both allow *unloading* as well, and there are functions to then get a function entry point by name.

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically do it. I will take linux case as an example. Since your parser working fine and generates machine code, you should be able to generate .so (for linux) or .dll for windows.

Next, load the library as

```
handle = dlopen(so_file_name, RTLD_LAZY);
```

Next get function pointer

```
func = dlsym(handle, "function_name");
```

Then you should be able to execute it as func()

One thing you need to experiment (in case you do not get desired result) is close and open the so file or dll file (you need to do only if required, else it may reduce performance)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you can generate the proper byte code.  So you could just ensure that you generate position independent code, write it into an executable piece of memory, and then call or create thread upon the code.  The simplest way would just be to cast the pointer to the base of the memory you wrote the code into as a function pointer, and then call it.

If you write your bytecode to avoid referencing different sections, and instead reference offsets from its loaded base, 'loading' the code is as easy as writing it to executable memory.  You could do a call/pop/jmp to find the base of the code once it begins executing.

Conversely, and probably the easiest solution, would be to just write the code out as function expecting arguments, that way you could pass the code's base and any other arguments to it, as you would with any other function, as long as you use the proper typedef for your function pointer, and the generated assembly handles the arguments properly.  As long as you avoid creating absolute jumps or data references to absolute addresses, you shouldn't have any issue.

Comment: But using some *existing* JIT library, or emitting some C code, is much easier.

Comment: I guess, sounds like they've already got the code generated.  I suppose it depends on how this program will be used in the future, and whether it is a long term or short term project.

Comment: It looks like they are generating *assembler* code (in some textual file), not *machine* code (in memory). This is practically quite different.

Comment: Oh, for some reason I thought they were generating the bytecode with their parser, guess I was mistaken.

Comment: @superultranova: your proposed idea is pretty close to what my team is trying to work on. We are not that far from machine code actually. and the generated code is optimized to a certain extent. Basile Starynkevitch also asked for details. I cannot reveal much except that the project is to be used on dedicated machines running it 24x7.

Comment: I think if I'm not mistaken, that is something virus and worms do. I know this is something people would frown upon as it is considered a hack but that is what comes to my mind when thinking of code injection.

Comment: @SimpleFellow  lots of things do this, and yes, some malicious programs do as well.  Your operating system does this when it loads a binary as well.  Code loading, for the most part, innocuous or otherwise, involves mapping executable memory, writing the code into the memory and jumping to a point within that code.  A lot of the JITs or other runtime code compilation tools are also going to do something similar.  If you're not being nefarious, there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: @superultranova:  nefarious? me? look at my nick. I'm just a Simple Fellow :D

Answer (score 1):

too late but I think it would help someone else.
in case you want to dynamically execute a piece of code, you can create an interpreter for this.
compile your expressions into some byte code then write the interpreter for executing this.

here is a tutorial about writing interpreters, but in python.

https://ruslanspivak.com/lsbasi-part1/

you can write it using c/c++

Comment: True, but generally speaking interpreters (even bytecode interpreters) are slower than compiled code or machine code or generated C or C++ code. I am aware of rare exceptions.

Comment: Yes that's true, but with an optimization you can gain almost near expected performance. again It's an Idea.

Comment: I don't think so, unless you consider [partial evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_evaluation) combined with [whole program optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocedural_optimization). Perhaps using [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/) could be in practice simpler